# Need guidance on a problem about oscillation from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, bounded-variation

I've been stuck on this particular problem for a while now:

*Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be an increasing function. If $x_1, ... ,x_n \in [a,b]$ are distinct, show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n o(f, x_i) < f(b) - f(a)$.*

It is clear that this is true, but I am finding it difficult to find a way to prove this in a manner that is valid. The proof that I did have for this problem seems to lack any substance and seems to draw on too many implicit assumptions that makes me almost certain it isn't correct. I think this comes from that fact that I do not see this problem in the way it should be seen, but I am just not exactly sure on what that is. I've tried other approaches that seemed promising at first, though it hasn't been of much help.

I would greatly appreciate any hints or guidance that will point me in the right direction of solving this problem.

Thanks.

Edit:

Note: $o(f, x_i) =  \lim_{\delta \to 0} [M(a, f, \delta) - m(a,f, \delta)]$

My proof: Assume $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n o(f, x_i) \geq  f(b) - f(a)$. Since $f$ is increasing, we can add $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n o(f, x_i)$ to $f(a)$. But this result is clearly not equal to $f(b)$, because $f$ is defined as increasing, nor is it greater than $f(b)$ because that would be outside of our range. Hence $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n o(f, x_i) < f(b) - f(a)$.

Comment: Could you show more of what you've proven so far?

Comment: You might want to elaborate what does the notation $o ( f, x_i )$ mean over here.

Comment: I imagine he means oscillation of a function at a point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)

Comment: See [this solution](http://math.bjart.li/Spivak1).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an oscillation *number* at each point associate an oscillation *interval*, $[\liminf f, \limsup f]$ near that point.

For a monotonic function the oscillation intervals at distinct points can intersect only at endpoints, and (another way to make the same statement) they have disjoint interiors.  Hence the oscillation intervals are a finite collection of non-overlapping intervals contained in $[f(a),f(b)]$.

Answer (score 1):

Select points $t_{i-1}<x_i<t_i$ and show that under the assumptions the oscillations satisfy

$$o(f,x_i)\le f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1}).$$

That is, show first the result for $n=1$ and then patch it together for general $n$.

Comment: I can see how the whole patching idea works, but I'm not quite sure how to show the result for an interval with n = 1

Comment: Then first write down, as demanded multiple times, what $o(f,x)$ is, then apply monotonicity to that formula. For instance starting with the general idea $o(f,x)= \inf\left\{\mathrm{diam}(f(U))\mid U\text{ is a  neighborhood of }x\right\}$